# Query Spring DATA with specific condition

Tags: java, spring, java-8, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to get a the account having a list of contracts with a status **'CA'** or **'CCR'**, I tried the query below and it works.

The problem is that i'd like to add a condition to my query, to get the accounts having the opposing contracts with different types.

Two opposing contracts are two contrats with different type. ( One contracts **H** and an other contract **A**)

The supported types are : Home Insurance & Auto Insurance ( **H** and **A** ).

```
@Query("select a from Account a full join a.contracts c join c.refStatusContract r where a.id=:id AND r.cdStatutContrat in ('CA','CCR')")
    Account getAccountHavingContractStatusActifOrInProcessOfTermination(@Param("id") long id);
```

***My need :***

**I want to check if exists two contracts attached to the account on my database, where the two contracts are opposed, and contracts authorised status are 'CA' or 'CCR'.**

Comment: Can you please elaborate more like what is opposing contract with some example.

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for you comment. I'll edit the text

Comment: I think you can use JPA Criteria APIs or Spring Data JPA `Specification` to build a query by condition, which is typesafe and more flexible(maybe looks a little complex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your problem correctly

So you want Accounts that:

1. Have Contracts with status 'CA' or 'CCR'
2. Have at least 2 Contracts, one with Type H and another with type A

Is this what you need?

```
@Query("select a 
        from Account a 
        full join a.contracts c 
        join c.refStatusContract r 
        where a.id=:id 
            AND r.cdStatutContrat in ('CA','CCR') 
            AND c.contractType in ('H', 'A')
        GROUP BY a
        having count(distinct c.contractType) > 1")
Account getAccountHavingContractStatusActifOrInProcessOfTermination(@Param("id") long id);
```

Is this what you need?